# Content Script is not working as it's supposed to on all web pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I am learning a bit by bit on chrome extensions. So I decided to do a small extension that will change any input field text color to blue. The problem was, that when I go to some websites like google and stack overflow the text is colored in blue but when I go to websites like facebook or twitter the fields were I write posts, write comments or search boxes are not colored(Note: I used inspect to make sure they are input fields). Any Idea why would that happen? and how can I fix that? 
Here's my code:

**Manifest.js:**

```
  {
    "name": "Colors",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "change text color",
     "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
     "js": ["contentScript.js"]     
   }
 ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon.png",
        "48": "images/icon.png",
        "128": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

**contentScript.js:**

```
var text_fields=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i;
for  (i=0;i<text_fields.length;i++){
    text_fields[i].style.color='blue';
}
```

**EDIT**:
So I have realized that some of the text fields are actually divs but there's no input field inside them(I seriously don't understand how), like the facebook "post field". So do u have any idea how to access these types of texts?

Comment: Can you link a specific twitter page that doesn't work? I tried running your code in the console at twitter.com/search-home and it worked fine. So not sure if it's a code issue or an extension issue.

Comment: @James The twitter home page doesn't work https://twitter.com/home . I tried using the console and it didn't work either

Comment: Hmm, I can't be of much help. Both work for me in Chrome and Firefox. If the problematic "inputs" aren't actually inputs, you would have to find some sort of common selector, which may not exist unfortunately.

Comment: Remove your content script and "js" entry in manifest.json, [use "css" instead](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively) with something like this: `input, [contenteditable] { color: blue !important }`